# Which of the following are the section of an XML document?

Tags: xml

1. Document Prolog
2. Body Parts
3. Header Parts
4. Root Element

Choose the answer:

```
A. 1,2,3
B. 2,3,4
C. 1,2,4
D. 1,2,3,4
```

(I think 1 and 4 is true, but why do the questions have more than that?)

Comment: Sorry, how to accept it? I am newbies here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I agree with your assessment: 1 & 4**

The XML Recommendation speaks of a [**prolog**](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-prolog):

```
[1]     document ::=     prolog element Misc*
[22]    prolog   ::=     XMLDecl? Misc* (doctypedecl Misc*)?
```

And a [**root element**](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-root):

> [Definition: There is exactly one element, called the root, or
>   document element, no part of which appears in the content of any other
>   element.] For all other elements, if the start-tag is in the content
>   of another element, the end-tag is in the content of the same element.
>   More simply stated, the elements, delimited by start- and end-tags,
>   nest properly within each other.

***Body*** and ***header*** are not terms generally used to describe XML documents.  Those are more commonly used in reference to [HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) messages, where Request and Response have a generic form, **[generic-message](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4)**, consisting of an ***[message-header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2)*** and ***[message-body](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.3)***:

```
generic-message = start-line
                  *(message-header CRLF)
                  CRLF
                  [ message-body ]
```